# GtkSharp 3.22 for Mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk3

I need to write a Gtk# application using Mono in a Linux environment. As I need specific features present in >=3.22 I can't use the default Gtk2 library.

Steps tried so far:

1. Installing Gtk3 library version 3.22.24.0 `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`.
2. In MonoDevelop, installing this [package](https://libraries.io/nuget/gtk-sharp-3) that should provide the most up-to-date Gtk# bindings, version 3.22.6.4.

Running a simple Gtk# application (as simple as `Gtk.Application.Init()` in main) triggers the following exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: libgtk-3.so.0
```

despite `ldconfig -p | grep libgtk` returning such a file under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 (x86), MonoDevelop 7.1 build 1291.

EDIT -- the issue is with MonoDevelop being installed via Flatpak, which provides a sandbox environment that "shields" the application from outside references, including the Gtk libraries. Therefore I installed Mono and compiled MonoDevelop following [this guide](https://kvssoft.wordpress.com/2016/12/13/building-monodevelop-on-ubuntu/) almost verbatim:

1. Add the repo list and update everything (Ubuntu's "factory-default" repos come with a 4.something version of Mono, which is not enough to compile Monodevelop as it lacks MSBuild):

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
   echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
   ```
2. Install required dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install -y autoconf automake cmake fsharp git gnome-sharp2 gtk-sharp2 libssh2-1-dev mono-complete referenceassemblies-pcl zlib1g-dev
   ```
3. Clone Monodevelop from git, with X being the version we choose from [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/releases) (tested with 7.3.0.708) and last argument being the folder where the source will be located:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git --branch monodevelop-X --depth 1 X
   ```
4. Configure, make and make install:

   ```
   ./configure --profile=stable --enable-release
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. Install GtkSharp 3:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
   ```

And that's it. Applications developed with the aforementioned [package](https://libraries.io/nuget/gtk-sharp-3) will then work correctly.

For some reason my app crashes when ran from within MonoDevelop (something to do with Glade files imported by `Builder.ExtendWithTemplate`) but works from command line `mono <appname>.exe`, so my solution might not be the best one, but that's a start.

Comment: did you figure out how to use GTK3 with MonoDevelop?